# Can you move/delete the .nuget folder?

Tags: linux

My home directory is running low on space, therefore I went through the folder to clean out some files.
There is a folder called `.nuget` with 6.9GB and another folder `.local/share/NuGet` with 1.8GB. This adds up to almost a quarter of the space for the user.

I'm not sure why exactly I even have those folders. I guess it has something to do with .NET, but not sure how and when they got installed. Maybe some dependency ...

Can I delete or move those folders? Or find out which programs/packages depend on or use them?

This is on Manjaro Gnome.

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio installed or using any .NET technologies?

Comment: I have VS code installed. Not sure if I have any .NET technologies, nor how I would find out. I couldn't find any dependencies for nuget in the package manager

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53047297/is-it-safe-to-delete-nuget-folder-inside-my-user-profile-folder

Comment: Thx, I don't know how I missed that one